# What is the process of DNS resolution when a user is searching for a site?

Tags: wireshark

I am learning about networking and using Wireshark. I saw that when a DNS request is made it starts with the PTR record and after the answer for the A record. I was wondering so if a user is searching for a site, the first query is the PTR record and not the A, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Those are actually completely independent.

To translate a domain name to IP addresses, *only* A/AAAA queries are needed.

The PTR queries are actually (most likely) sent by *Wireshark itself* – if you have enabled "View → Name Resolution → Network Layer", then Wireshark will try to translate the source & destination IP addresses *back* to domain names, for additional clarity.